# React Native - What is the difference between size and displaySize in ImageEditor.cropImage()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the difference between the `size` and `displaySize` property of `ImageEditor.cropImage()` method? What these two properties represents? A little example will be more appreciated if done with an image. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between these two properties is:

- The `size` property specifies the actual size of the image which we are
  going to crop.
- The `displaySize` property specifies the size to which we want to
  scale the image after cropping.

**For example:**

```
cropData = {
   offset: ...
   size: {width: actualWidthOfTheImage, height: actualHeightOfTheImage},
   displaySize: {width: newWidthOfTheImage, height: newHeightOfTheImage}
   resizeMode: ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**size**: It is the actual size of the image

**displaySize**: It is the size of the image to which you want to scale it.

Example - **@3x** assets at a *virtual resolution* of `2208×1242` (with `736x414` points)

```
cropData = {
  size:{width: 414, height: 736},
  displaySize:{width: 1242, height: 2208},        
  resizeMode:'contain', 
}
try {
  await ImageEditor.cropImage(uri
        cropData, (successURI) => { console.log('Success') }, 
        (error) =>{ console.log('Error,',error) }
      )
 }
```